# how to fix error E0026 c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I don't know how to fix this error with /give 
command is a simple char command;
but anyway my error is "too many character in character constant"
update if i take away the e in give it works bit i dont want to

```
      system("pause")   
  if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN))
  {
        cin >> command >> argument >> argument1;
        cin.clear();
        if (command == '/tp')
        {
            if (map[argument][argument1] == ' ')
            {
                map[y][x] = ' ';
                int y = argument;
                int x = argument1;
                map[y][x] = '@';
            }
        }
        if (command == '/give')
        {

        }
```

Comment: you are trying to compare a string but as per code it is a character. Try replacing ' with " and give it a try..

Comment: can you explain what you are trying in that condition, where code is failing to compile?

Comment: @nevihs dos'nt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C/`C++` single characters are surrounded by `'` `'`

```
char c = 'h';
```

Strings of things are surrounded by `"` `"`

```
char * s = "hello";
std::string ss = "hello";
```

This became more complicated, when the guys in the US found about other languages and scripts. 
The 256 values of a char were not sufficient to allow for regular characters.
They then allowed a small number of extra values in `'` `'` to define extended character values.

It looks like you need strings.  Assuming `command` is a `std::string` then the code should be ...

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN))
{
    cin >> command >> argument >> argument1;
    cin.clear();
    if (command == "/tp")
    {
        if (map[argument][argument1] == ' ') 
        {
            map[y][x] = ' ';
            int y = argument;
            int x = argument1;
            map[y][x] = '@';
        }
    }
    if (command == "/give")
    {

    }
}
```

`command` needs to be something which has the ability to hold multiple characters and has an `operator >>` defined for it.